# How do I correct undesirable syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

My current Vim installation on Windows appears to have default syntax highlighting for Markdown, which is nice.

However, there is one particular highlight which I don't really like, and that is the highlight for emphasized text:

[image]

I find it rather distracting that it changes all emphasized text to this bright yellow color. Is there any way I can customize that?

Comment: Use gvim to have proper italics or wsl vim in mintty/wsltty or windows terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Once you find the highlight group (`markdownItalic`, in this case), you can customize it as follows:

```
augroup fix_markdown_italic
  autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * highlight markdownItalic …
augroup end
```

1. The `*` pattern makes this override effective for any colorscheme; you might prefer instead to target a specific one. (This also assumes the colorscheme is more at fault than the syntax rules; you could probably get away with putting the `:highlight markdownItalic …` bit in `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`, too.)
2. Replace the `…` with any custom `:highlight` arguments you want.